# Create new Pull Request from a branch on a reverted changes to develop branch

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have a weird issue or I just cannot understand it at the moment .
I had some 5 PRs ***merged*** into **develop** (from feature **branches**) but needed to be merged in another branch *(ex: release/release1 - branched from develop)* .

So I reverted the develop branch (created a new commit) with the last known commit pre-MERGE by doing this :

```
# Create a backup of master branch
git branch backup_master

# Point master to '56e05fce' and
# make working directory the same with '56e05fce'
git reset --hard 56e05fce

# Point master back to 'backup_master' and
# leave working directory the same with '56e05fce'.
git reset --soft backup_master

# Now working directory is the same '56e05fce' and
# master points to the original revision. Then we create a commit.
git commit -a -m "Revert to 56e05fce"

# Delete unused branch
git branch -d backup_master
```

Now I need to recreate those PRs but it seems commits are both in the **feature** branches and **develop** one due to merges I guess , so basically there is no change , even though files are totally different.

How can I address this , maybe removing commits from history .. I dont know what to do .

Thanks

PS : I can think of creating new branches from develop and cherry-pick commits of every PR one by one and recreate PRs since cherry-pick changes SHAs due to parent change . Is this a good approach ?

Answer (score 0):

> Now I need to recreate those PRs but it seems [all the] commits [I want to merge] are [already] both in the `feature` branches and `develop` one due to merges ...

That's correct: merge is about *combining work since a common starting point* and there is no *new* work since the common starting point.

You can view it like this.  Remember that in the drawing below, older commits are to the left and newer commits are towards the right, and the *set of commits* that is "in" any given branch name is *all the commits Git can find by starting from the branch name and working backwards* (i.e., leftwards):

```
                 E--F--G   <-- feature1
                /       \
 ...--o--o--o--D---M1----M2--U   <-- mainline
          \       /
           A--B--C   <-- feature2
```

When Git made merge `M1`, the picture looked like this:

```
 ...--o--●--o--D   <-- mainline
          \
           A--B--C   <-- feature2
```

The commit I filled in to make a solid bullet ● character is the *merge base:* the common starting point.  Git compares the snapshot in ● to that in `D` to see what changed on the main line, and compares the snapshot in ● to that in `C` to see what changed on the feature branch.  Git then *combines* these changes, applies the *combined* changes to the ● snapshot, and uses that to make merge commit `M1` to add to the main line (which you first switch to before running `git merge`, even if you do this using the GitHub clicky web interface):

```
 ...--o--●--o--D---M1   <-- mainline
          \       /
           A--B--C   <-- feature2
```

Since commit `C` is now "on" the main line branch—Git can get to it by starting at `M1` and working backwards (leftwards) and down, in the same way that Git can work backwards across to `D`—the common starting point for `feature2` and `mainline` is now commit `C`.  There is no *new* work here.

Adding `feature1` back into the drawing, though, we see that the common starting point for commits `M1` and `G` is commit `D`, so Git *can* merge commit `G` into commit `M1` and update the name `mainline` to produce new merge commit `M2`:

```
                 E--F--G   <-- feature1
                /       \
 ...--o--o--o--D---M1----M2   <-- mainline
          \       /
           A--B--C   <-- feature2
```

You then used the somewhat tricky reset-and-then-reset-soft sequence to copy some old commit's snapshot—perhaps, e.g., the leftmost `o` snapshot, or perhaps `D`'s snapshot—into a new commit `U` that "undoes" the two merges, at least in terms of the set of files stored in each commit:

```
                 E--F--G   <-- feature1
                /       \
 ...--o--o--o--D---M1----M2--U   <-- mainline
          \       /
           A--B--C   <-- feature2
```

But the merge base of `mainline` and `feature1` is still `G`, and the merge base of `mainline` and `feature2` is still `C`, i.e., those two features are *still merged*.

Note that if you picked the leftmost `o` snapshot to use in `U`, you also undid two more `o`s and `D`, in effect.  As far as Git is concerned, whatever is in any given commit's snapshot is the *right* snapshot for that commit.  So whatever you put in commit `U`'s snapshot, that's the *right* snapshot.  If you want a different snapshot, you must construct it in some way.

> How can I address this , maybe removing commits from history ...

You *can* force the name `mainline` back to point to commit `D`, or `M1`, or `M2`.  *All the existing commits continue to exist while you do this* and if they have been copied to *other* Git repositories, those other Git repositories can send them back to your own Git repository.  As Git is generally greedy for *new* commits, it's far too easy to wind up with these commits getting back in.  That's why we don't "remove commits from history" like this very often: they're not *really* gone unless they're gone from *every clone*, and that tends to be very hard to achieve unless you have exquisite control over all clones.

> I can think of creating new branches from develop and cherry-pick commits of every PR one by one and recreate PRs since cherry-pick changes SHAs due to parent change . Is this a good approach ?

In fact, `git rebase`—which works by repeatedly cherry-picking commits—has an explicit option to do exactly this.  This option [has several spellings](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

> `--no-ff`
> `--force-rebase`
> `-f`
>       Individually replay all rebased commits instead of fast-forwarding over the unchanged ones. This ensures that the entire history of the rebased branch is composed of new commits.
>
> You may find this helpful after reverting a topic branch merge, as this option recreates the topic branch with fresh commits so it can be remerged successfully without needing to "revert the reversion" (see the [revert-a-faulty-merge How-To](https://git-scm.com/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge) for details).

Follow the link and read the "how-to" document.  Think about what `git merge` does and what you want people to see when they view the history (i.e., the commits that they can find by having Git start at the end and work backwards).  This will lead you to the answer you prefer, which may not be the same as answers others prefer.  Git provides tools, not solutions; you must choose which tools you like, and how to use them, to achieve the results *you* want to get.